# Placement of labels in assembly language program

Tags: assembly

Can labels for address location be placed in middle of assembly language program? Like

```
         ORG 100
100      LDA SUB
101      CMA
102 SUB, DEC -23
103      INC
104      ADD MIN
105 MIN, DEC 83
106      STA DIF
107 DIF, HEX 0
108      HLT
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this depends on your assembler, but using nasm, fasm, yasm, masm and gnu as, yes you can and you typically use labels for jmp targets etc.

Specifically, a normal label is similar in use to `static` functions in C.

In NASM, those you mark with `global labelname` are exported from the object and can be referenced from other compilation units and linked up by a linker.

The syntax for nasm would be:

```
global myfunc

myfunc:

    <stuff>

myotherlabel:

    <stuff>

    jne myotherlabel

    <stuff>
```